# Inserting a child object with a parent when the parent already exists with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I would like to insert an child object (see class definitions below) which has a relationship with a parent object which may or may not already exists in the database, and then get the generated primary key for the child. I tried using both `Session.add` and `Session.merge` but I'm running into problems with both.

1. Using `Session.add` does not work when the parent object already exists in the table. For example, the following fails:

```py
# Create a parent with id 1
parent = Parent(id = 1)
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(parent)
    session.commit()

...

# Later, add a child whose parent is the one with id 1. 
# I know the parent id and don't need to fetch it from
# the database, thus I'm directly creating the parent object. 
parent = Parent(id = 1)
child = Child(parent = parent)
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(child)
    session.commit()
    print("child.id = " + str(child.id))
```

It produces:

```
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "parent_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

SQLAlchemy is trying to add the parent again but complains that the primary key "1" already exists.

2. Using `Session.merge` works but I cannot get the generated id for the new child:

```py
# The Parent with id = 1 now exists in the parent table

# Add the child with the parent using merge
parent = Parent(id = 1)
child = Child(parent = parent)
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.merge(child)
    session.commit()
    print("child.id = " + str(child.id))
```

This shows `child.id = None`.

I'm probably not approaching the right way and I'd very much appreciate some directions.

Here are the example class definitions:

```py
    class Parent(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'parent'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)

        children = relationship("Child", back_populates = "parent")

    class Child(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'children'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
        parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id"), nullable = False)

        parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates = "children")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of arbitrarily creating `parent = Parent(id = 1)` you should check if it already exists:

```py
# retrieve parent from database …
parent1 = session.get(Parent, 1)
if not parent1:
    # … and create if not found
    session.add(parent1 := Parent(id=1, name="Homer"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if there would be a way to avoid manually checking if the object was present in the db with `get`, for example if that would be part of the magic SQLAlchemy does with the relationship objects. But I guess not…?