# SQLAlchemy: Add child if parent is unknown to exist

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, parent-child

I have a maria-database with several tables. One of them contains essential metadata and was constructed like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, Unicode, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, declarative_base, Session
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint


Model = declarative_base(bind=sql_engine)

class Meta(Model):

    data_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(Unicode, index=True)
    lastname = Column(Unicode, index=True)
    __tablename__ = 'meta'
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('firstname', 'lastname'),
    )
```

As you can see, in my case every firstname-lastname-combination is unique. Now, new data with additional attributes (apart from firstname and lastname) is coming in.  Since this happens regularly, I do not want to mess around with the meta-table but create a  new table for these attributes, like:

```
class AttrsNew(Model):
    
    data_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('meta.data_id'), primary_key=True)
    weight = Column(Float)
    height = Column(Float)
    __tablename__ = 'attrs_new'
    meta = relationship('Meta', back_populates='attrs_new')
```

I used to add data like this:

```
Model = automap_base()
Model.prepare(sql_engine, reflect=True)
Meta = Model.classes.meta
AttrsNew = Model.classes.attrs_new

entry_1 = Meta(firstname='John', lastname='Doe')
entry_1.attrs_new_collection = [AttrsNew(weight=80, height=180)]

entry_2 = Meta(firstname='Amanda', lastname='Smith')
entry_2.attrs_new_collection = [AttrsNew(weight=60, height=165)]

with Session(sql_engine) as session:
    session.add_all([entry_1, entry_2])
    session.commit()
```

This worked fine. But due to the UniqueConstraint it fails if the meta-table already has an entry for John Doe. Is there an elegant way to handle this? I do not know beforehand if a person already has an entry. I only have the name information not the data_id. Of course I can check this manually and add the according data_id to the AttrsNew-object and only commit this child-object without the parent Meta-object. But this smells wrong and it requires a case discrimination. Also, I have to do this A LOT, so performance might become an issue.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69221734/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson While this is related, it does not solve my issue. I do not know the PrimaryKey-value but only `firstname` and `lastname`. `session.get()` does not seem to be applicable in this case.

Comment: You could use `select(Meta).where(and_(Meta.firstname == "John", Meta.lastname == "Doe"))` instead of `session.get()` in this case. The point is to get the object into the session by trying to retrieve it, and only create it if it doesn't already exist.